# ReactJS Hook useState with Key press event

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm building a piano that display some `css` style when user "press" some keyboard button (`keydown`) ( click `multiples` different button at the same time also allow). When user stop pressing (`keyup`) , simply remove those `css` style .

Ex: click and hold "A", "B", "C" will add active class to them , release "C" only remove active class to "C".

I plan to do it with react hook like this :

```js
  const [press, setPress] = useState([]); //Hook state
  
  // store the keyboard user click into an array
  const keyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.repeat) {
      return;
    }
    setPress((oldArr) => [...oldArr, e.key]);
  };
  
  // remove only the one that user release 
  const keyUp = (e) => {
    const keyRemove = press.filter((key) => key !== e.key);
    setPress(keyRemove);
  };

// add key press event listener
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
    return function cleanup() {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp);
    };
  }, []);
  
  //just pass the press arr to child element
    return (
    <div className="main">
        <Child press={press} /> 
    </div>
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

The `keydown` event work's fine , but the `keyup` keep `reset` the `press` array back to empty . I don't understand why this work like this . Can someone explain it for me ? Thank in advance

Comment: Your `keyUp` function that is tied to the window event has an old reference to the initial instance of `press`

Comment: use a function in your state setter like this: `setPress(prev => prev.filter((key) => key !== e.key));`

Comment: Thank @Martin , can you tell me what is this behavior call ? I want to research more about it

Comment: Its called [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). You create two functions `keyDown` and `keyUp`. Those two functions are registered with your window events. And they are "frozen in time". All later functions you create when your state changes and your component is rendered again are not connected to the window events. Therefore you must pay attention to not put state references in the closures of your functions.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your logic in `keyUp`. You need to update the `filter`:

```
const keyUp = (e) => {
  setPress(press.filter((key) => key !== e.key));
};
```

Comment: No, that fixes nothing, that still uses a stale reference of `press`

Comment: I'd made a mistake in the `filter` but I don't think correct it will fix the problem I'm dealing

Comment: Do you try `setPress(prev => prev.filter((key) => key !== e.key));` as comment above

Answer (score 0):

changing the key up filter works for me

```
const keyRemove = press.filter(function(value, index, arr){ 
        return value !== e.key;
});
```

Comment: But your answer is basically just the same answer as the earlier one from Viet.

Comment: That's why I upvoted him.  His answer wasn't there when I started working on this and I didn't refresh the page